# How to digital sign a PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, service, digital-signature

After some searching how I could digital sign a PDF document with PHP I couldn't really find a working solution. Does anybody know how to do this? Or do you know a third-party service which can sign PDF's for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setasign appears to offer a commercial solution for signing PDFs already created - http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/setapdf-signer/sign-pdf.php

Alternatively, TCPDF (Google it, it won't let me post a second URL), allows you to generate signed PDFs on the fly.

Comment: Do you know if TCPDF is reliable? As I read about some issues that the signing of PDF's did not work.

Comment: It's been reliable for the tasks I've needed it for - but that hasn't included signing PDFs. I'd certainly suggest giving it a try.