# Signing PDFs programmatically in linux

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, pdf-generation, certificate

I'm trying to digitally **sign PDFs server-side**. So far I found that I can do this using MyPDFSigner, but it's far from my needs. Also I don't believe that this is the only option here.

**How to sign pdfs in linux?** Does Adobe provide any tool for server-side-signinig PDF documents (it does, see edit)?

It would be nice if it has python api, but command line tool will do too.

**EDIT:**
I found that its possible using **Adobe LiveCycle Digital Signatures ES2** which is **java appliaction**, but it comes with Adobe LiveCycle which is **quite expensive**.

Comment: The closest to this I've found (short of implementing it yourself) is described in this SO question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378247/how-to-digitally-sign-pdf-files The accepted solution there is a Java library ([iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php)) that I'm assuming you could turn into an executable, then in turn, call from python. Far from ideal, but it's offered under the [AGPL](http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/agpl.php) (as well as commercial, if this is a problem for you) so it doesn't have to be expensive.