# Reading a digital signature from a file, c#, then verifying it

Tags: c#, c++, import, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I've been looking around, and see that visual studio c++ has some "native" tools to remove a digital signatures.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680214(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Of course I am doing this with documents, specifically for pdf files so I don't know how that function would work since it seems intended for images.

If it can remove it, could it also read it and return the signature? Right now I am using c# and wanted to have the program actually capture the digital signature so it can be verified, but one step at a time. Everything I read about System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates seems to indicate that it can only do any of its functions once the files are assigned X509Certificates related classes.

I've also never imported c++ code into c#, but I know it is possible. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f18d1d1c-0d14-4ff2-8244-337f58818ef9/how-to-use-c-code-in-c?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

Comment: After posting this, I found this useful line. 

string filePath = "C:/path/to/file.dll";
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
        Module module = assembly.GetModules().First();
        X509Certificate certificate = module.GetSignerCertificate(); 

Don't know how that would work on byte arrays.

Comment: `Image` in those functions mean EXE files.  None of that has anything to do with what you want.

Comment: You need to use the PDF file format.

Comment: Which ones does that?/How do you do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/379033/34397

Comment: There was issues with iTextSharp, the people I am working with told me to try to avoid using it. However, I will use it if there is no other way.

Comment: @lockgar then there's our SecureBlackbox ( https://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pdf.php ) which does more in regards to PDF signatures and includes support and samples.

Comment: You can also use the [CoSign C# API](http://developer.arx.com/quick-start/sapi-local/) to verify documents.

Comment: The issue was with GPL, I can't use anything that has a GPL license.

Comment: No of those seem to be able to actually verify a digital signature that has already been signed onto a file....