# How to Generate PDF with digital signature in Qt C++

Tags: c++, macos, qt, pdf-generation, qprinter

I am developing an application for MAC OS X (in Qt c++) in which I want to Generate a PDF with digital signature. I am successful to making pdf `void QPrinter::setOutputFormat (QPrinter::PdfFormat)` using this. But I am failed to make this pdf digitally signed in qt.

Comment: The question is specific to Acrobat PDF and not Qt. You can use Qt but that is just a tool.

Comment: You may need to use a third party library if I'm reading [Qt's documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF) correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use a third party library if I'm reading [Qt's documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF) correctly. Adding digital signatures without third party libraries is a very difficult task. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378247/digitally-sign-pdf-files) discussion, doing it manually should be avoided. This [website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14488/E-signing-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp) also goes into depth about the issue. (Mind you, both of these pages are working in C#, not C++, but the subject/problem is highly parallel.)

I found [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1408543) in a forum on Adobe's Website; which links to [Datalogic's website](http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdflibrary/). There is a free-trial option available. The library is exclusively in C/C++. "Extensive" code samples are included.

If you use Datalogic's library, which is Adobe's preferred library, you should be on the road to success.