# How to sign a PDF with a signature from a CA in a Microsoft AD by a client script or program

Tags: c#, pdf, active-directory, signature, certificate-authority

The most of you will know the functionality of the Acrobat Reader where you can choose a certificate to sign a PDF document with a [digital signature](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/certificate-based-signatures.html). I want to automate this by a script or program but I have two Problems:

1. How can I interact with our internal CA of our Microsoft AD to get the private and public Key (or in other words: a `.pvk` and a `.cer` file or bundled in a `.pfx` file) like the user would himself choose the right certificate in the Acrobat Reader. I hope this is possible by a script or program on every client of our network.
2. Is there a open source framework/library (programming language does'nt matter) to attach a digital signatur to a PDF like the [Adobe SDK](https://basquang.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/add-digital-signature-to-a-pdf-programmatically-using-adobe-sdk-and-microsoft-net/) way?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378247/digitally-sign-pdf-files

Comment: Ok, this would be the answer to the second question, thank you linuxrocks!