# Write a Digital Signing Programme on C# using a Smart Card to sign a batch of .xml documents

Tags: c#, signature, digital

I am new to digital signatures. I have spent the last couple of days learning about how digital signatures work, cryptography etc.

My task is to sign a batch of .xml documents with a digital signature that use PKCS#11 (smart card) using C# and zip all the signed documents and send it to a Web API of our client.

Everytime I used the smart card it installs a certificate on the browser.

The smart card is from a root CA so there is no needs of a verification of a certified chain and check each certificate.

Question is .. how do I write the code or better where do I start? Any documentation will be  I have tried to dig documentation .. to no avail.

Only resources are available on JAVA and they are using some java applets.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378247/digitally-sign-pdf-files

Comment: Also have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: It looks that you need to combine:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-encrypt-xml-elements-with-asymmetric-keys - for signing xmls

with

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-access-hardware-encryption-devices

with 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-access-hardware-encryption-devices - for obtaining key from smart card.